# How to get datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Well Sorry about the title...
Actually I'm trying to do something like the below table.

[image]

Delay is **int64** Dtype and Due_date is **datetime64[ns]** Dtype

First I try to convert the delay column in datetime using this:

```
df['Delay'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Delay'], unit='D')
```

but it's returning default value i.e. 02-01-1970

then I try to add directly using this:

```
df['Output_date'] = (df['Delay'].add(df['Due_date']))
```

but this one is also not working....
can anyone help me with this.

I'm a student and new to this area.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) to variable for not overwrite original column and add it to datetimes created by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
delay = pd.to_timedelta(df['Delay'], unit='D')
df['Output_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Due_date'], dayfirst=True).add(delay)
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael...
Can you explain it a bit more, why not overwrite the 'delay' column.